# Swift type reflexion initialization with parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, initialization

I'm trying to create an object from a class that is passed on to a function of mine. The problem is that I'm unable to pass any arguments to its constructor because I can't seem to `initialize` the class with parameters.

This is the code I have so far:

```
class func invokeService<T: Initable>(service: String, returningClass: T.Type, completionHandler handler: ((T) -> ())) {

        var interfaceObject = returningClass()

        interfaceObject.self(data: service as Dictionary <String, AnyObject>)

        handler(interfaceObject)
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
'(data: Dictionary <String, AnyObject>)-> $T2' is not identical to 'T'
```

Answer (score 1):

Some strange things are going on in your code, as far as I can see (I am no Swift expert either). Specifically, you are trying to initialise the same object twice.

I am assuming that your `Initable` protocol is defined as:

```
protocol Initable {
    init(data:Dictionary <String, AnyObject>)
}
```

And that you want to instantiate an object from that. Then the correct way to do that would be:

```
class func invokeService<T: Initable>(service: String, returningClass: T.Type, completionHandler handler: ((T) -> ())) {

    var dict = // create a Dictionary <String, AnyObject>
    var interfaceObject = returningClass(data: dict)

    handler(interfaceObject)
}
```

Now your remaining problem is how to convert the `service` to a dictionary. You cannot simply cast a string to a dictionary for obvious reasons.

You want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24735880/908621) to another question as well.

Pedantic note: using dynamic typing and initialising an anonymous class like this is very advanced usage that should only be needed in very extreme cases. Usually an [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is a better way to achieve a similar goal.