# How to check type against type parameter?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a UIViewController extensions that gets the first child view controller with a certain type.

I tried:

```
func getChildViewController(#type:UIViewController.Type) -> UIViewController? {
    for vc:UIViewController in self.childViewControllers as [UIViewController] {
        if vc is type { //<-- 'type is not a type'
            return vc
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And:

```
func getChildViewController(#type:Type) -> UIViewController? { // "Type", doesn't exist
    for vc:UIViewController in self.childViewControllers as [UIViewController] {
        if vc is type {
            return vc
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And this (partially derived from [How to pass a class type as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308975/how-to-pass-a-class-type-as-a-function-parameter)):

```
func getChildViewController<T>(#type:T.Type) -> UIViewController? {
    for vc:UIViewController in self.childViewControllers as [UIViewController] {
        if vc is type { //<-- 'type is not a type'
            return vc
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Nothing works! How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last example, change

```
if vc is type
```

to

```
if vc is T
```

`T` is the type you’re looking for, whereas `T.Type` is a metatype giving information about the type `T`.  All you’re really using `T.Type` for is to fix `T` to be the type that you want when you call `getChildViewController`.

Comment: Ohh, ok, that's somehow weird. I expected the variable ("type") to be the type. In Java for example it's possible to do this: `void foo(Class<?> a) {
  String b = "";
  if (a.isInstance(b)) {}
 }`

Comment: Maybe I can't judge this correctly, but this syntax has something counterintuitive. Anyways, it works, thanks!